# MSWord Search in a macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I search without specifying the range, the search starts at the active page:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "house"
    .Replacement.Text = "apartment"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
```

If I use a range, it always starts at the beginning of the range

```
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).select
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "house"
    .Replacement.Text = "apartment"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
```

Anyone know a way to start the search in the active page while using a range?

By active page,  I mean the page with the cursor.

Also, I need to search footnotes and endnotes. That's the reason for using storyranges, which seems to force the search to start at the beginning of the document.

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'active' page in Word. A page may be visible, yet the selected range may not be on that page. Please edit your question to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Neither of your examples uses `Range.Find`. They both use `Selection.Find`

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Dim findRange As Range
Set findRange = Selection.Range
With findRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "house"
    .Replacement.Text = "apartment"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True
    .Execute
End With
```

Please note that as you have set `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` it makes no difference where `Find` starts as it will search the entire document anyway.

Comment: «it makes no difference where Find starts as it will search the entire document anyway» Except that if the insertion point is within 'house' (e.g. 'ho|use'), that instance won't be replaced.